# In python, can we set table name as a variable using Sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

For example:

```
import Sqlite3
def ChangeTable(c,a):
    c.execute('''DELETE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE id = ?''',(a,))
```

This way I can change the value of a and process the database with a function in python.
But how can I do something similar with Table names?
This way I can use one function to handle different tables.

Comment: You could build the string, and then pass that to the c.execute statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing in table names is made to not work intentionally, since dynamically using table names in SQL queries is generally a bad idea. If you're in a situation where you end up dynamically wanting to do stuff with table names, you should think about redesigning your database and make it [relational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). It's hard to give specific advice about how to do this in your case, since we don't know how your database is arranged.

The other answer involves using string formatting in SQL queries. This is very bad coding practice, since it makes your code vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). The [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) documentation says to *never* do this, in fact. You don't want to have a [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) situation on your hands.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use variables for table names. You have to perform string concatenation or substitution. As an example, using an F-string (Python >= 3.6):

```
def change_table(table_name, id):
    c.execute(f'DELETE FROM {table_name} WHERE id = ?', (id,))
```

with more meaningful variable names...
Triple quoting is not required here but useful for multiline statements.

Comment: Using python string formatting is a very bad idea since it makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection. The [sqlite documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) says to NEVER do this...

Comment: That would be a vulnerability if the OP actually relied on external input to determine the table name. Hopefully this is not happening here. Although I agree it may be better to rethink the DB design or use conditional statements to avoid doing dynamic SQL.